# why does installing imblearn with pip is failing?

Tags: imblearn

I am trying to install the python package "imblearn" to balanace datasets,
with the command pip install imblearn.
but it keeps failing.

trying from cmdand from PowerShell with admin privileges,

with regular pip command, and with git clone to the repo and then pip install.
everything is failing.
the error is:

```
C:\Users\ronke>pip install imblearn
Collecting imblearn
  Using cached imblearn-0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.9 kB)
Collecting imbalanced-learn
  Using cached imbalanced_learn-0.10.1-py3-none-any.whl (226 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.3.2 in c:\networks\python3.8\lib\site-packages (from imbalanced-learn->imblearn) (1.6.3)
Collecting scikit-learn>=1.0.2
  Using cached scikit-learn-1.2.0.tar.gz (7.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [73 lines of output]
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.10" and platform_system == "Windows" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"' don't match your environment
      Collecting setuptools<60.0
        Using cached setuptools-59.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (952 kB)
      Collecting wheel
        Using cached wheel-0.38.4-py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
      Collecting Cython>=0.29.24
        Using cached Cython-0.29.32-py2.py3-none-any.whl (986 kB)
      Collecting oldest-supported-numpy
        Using cached oldest_supported_numpy-2022.11.19-py3-none-any.whl (4.9 kB)
      Collecting scipy>=1.3.2
        Using cached scipy-1.9.3.tar.gz (42.1 MB)
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
        Installing backend dependencies: started
        Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error

        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
        exit code: 1

        [37 lines of output]
        + meson setup --prefix=c:\networks\python3.8 C:\Users\ronke\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n9p_hxtm\scipy_cef72cd617894d719469ea6e03d892cb C:\Users\ronke\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n9p_hxtm\scipy_cef72cd617894d719469ea6e03d892cb\.mesonpy-jv80z8m8\build --native-file=C:\Users\ronke\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n9p_hxtm\scipy_cef72cd617894d719469ea6e03d892cb\.mesonpy-native-file.ini -Ddebug=false -Doptimization=2
        The Meson build system
        Version: 1.0.0
        Source dir: C:\Users\ronke\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n9p_hxtm\scipy_cef72cd617894d719469ea6e03d892cb
        Build dir: C:\Users\ronke\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n9p_hxtm\scipy_cef72cd617894d719469ea6e03d892cb\.mesonpy-jv80z8m8\build
        Build type: native build
        Project name: SciPy
        Project version: 1.9.3
        Activating VS 17.1.3
        C compiler for the host machine: cl (msvc 19.31.31105 "Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.31.31105 for x64")
        C linker for the host machine: link link 14.31.31105.0
        C++ compiler for the host machine: cl (msvc 19.31.31105 "Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.31.31105 for x64")
        C++ linker for the host machine: link link 14.31.31105.0
        Host machine cpu family: x86_64
        Host machine cpu: x86_64
        Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-but-set-variable: NO
        Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-but-set-variable: NO (cached)
        Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-function: NO
        Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-conversion: NO
        Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-misleading-indentation: NO
        Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-incompatible-pointer-types: NO
        Library m found: NO

        ..\..\meson.build:57:0: ERROR: Unknown compiler(s): [['ifort'], ['gfortran'], ['flang'], ['pgfortran'], ['g95']]
        The following exception(s) were encountered:
        Running `ifort --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
        Running `ifort -V` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
        Running `gfortran --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
        Running `gfortran -V` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
        Running `flang --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
        Running `flang -V` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
        Running `pgfortran --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
        Running `pgfortran -V` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
        Running `g95 --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
        Running `g95 -V` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"

        A full log can be found at C:\Users\ronke\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n9p_hxtm\scipy_cef72cd617894d719469ea6e03d892cb\.mesonpy-jv80z8m8\build\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
        [end of output]

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: metadata-generation-failed

      Encountered error while generating package metadata.

      See above for output.

      note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
      hint: See above for details.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Does someone know how to fix it?

thanks

Ron

Answer (score 0):

I've condensed this to show the key part of the error:

```
Collecting scipy>=1.3.2
  Using cached scipy-1.9.3.tar.gz (42.1 MB)
  ...
  ..\..\meson.build:57:0: ERROR: Unknown compiler(s): [['ifort'], ['gfortran'], ['flang'], ['pgfortran'], ['g95']]
```

Which is saying that `scipy==1.9.3` failed to compile because a Fortran compiler was not availalbe.

---

This is probably caused by a 32-bit version of Python / Windows, since pre-compiled `scipy` and `scikit-learn` wheels are being phased out for 32-bit systems, and we're no longer testing 32-bit Windows in `imblearn` (see [PR#936](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn/pull/936)).

One possible fix is to install a copy of Python with [Anaconda or Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/windows.html), then:

```bash
conda install -c conda-forge imbalanced-learn
```

Comment: thanks. I installed miniconda and installed the imblearn package in the conda prompt. but the pycharm does not recognize the package. should I connect them somehow?

Comment: Yes, pycharm has docs for configuring https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/conda-support-creating-conda-virtual-environment.html

Comment: But I have many packages installed with pip. I want the imblearn package and all the rest from pip

Comment: You can reinstall them. `pip` and `conda` are fairly compatible with one another.

Comment: Is there a fix that will let me install it in pip?

Comment: Maybe, there are several alternatives. (1) Are you comfortable with the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)? (2) Are you using a 64-bit Windows operating system? (3) Does installing `scipy` and `scikit-learn` with `conda` and `imbalanced-learn` with `pip` fit your needs?

Comment: (1) I have ubuntu wsl on my computer, know basic unix commands. (2) yes, windows 10 with 64 bit. (3) I already have scikit learn an scipy in pip, I just want to add imblearn to them

Comment: You can *probably* make it work by installing an old version of `scipy` like `pip install scipy==1.3.2` then running `pip install imbalanced-learn`. But this doesn't really fix the problem and will be an issue again if you need to update a package in the future.

Comment: You also *probably* want to look into Python environments soon. You don't have to use conda if you don't want too (there are other options like [venv](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/)). A lot of people don't know about environments until they metaphorically shoot themselves in the foot.